# How to put external audio or video file in emulator android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-audiomanager, android-music-player

I am a beginner android app developer. and right now I am developing an android app 
that can fetch all the audio files from the phone and play them,
but my actual phone is malfunctioning and due to COVID 19  lockdown all the service center is 
closed so **I am searching the way so that I can put the audio file inside the emulator and test our app.**